# Protecting PU furniture

Tags: furniture, protection

I have a less then 3 year old chair,  just discovered that it is made from PU, and the PU (on the seat of the chair) is peeling off into lots of shreds and messing up the carpet.  (The chair is less then 3 years old)

The replacement chair I purchased is also PU (not many options open to me).   I don't want it to suffer the same fate, and I'm wondering what I can do to protect it.

I note that the room is sometimes exposed to fairly high temperatures as it is in an attic (up to 45c I imagine).  As I work from home the chair gets a lot of use.  I'm wondering if the temperature cause the PU to degrade, and if so, what I can do (other then leave the air-con on all the time) to protect the chair.

Comment: What does PU mean?

Comment: @Harper PU = Polyurethane (but commonly labelled as PU on things) - it is a common "fake leather" plastic.